# Ionic 3 descarga de imágenes por url Error 503

Tags: ionic, imagen, url, ionic3, descarga

Muy buenas a todos :). Resulta que estoy aprendiendo a usar IONIC 3 y estoy elaborando un proyecto en el que tengo en un servidor almacenadas una serie de imágenes. Cuando se usa la app por primera vez se descarga toda la información en la BBDD del dispositivo y también las imágenes correspondientes. Para ello uso:

```
    download(url, carpeta, file){
       return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
          let path = null;
          if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
             path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
          }else{
             path = this.file.dataDirectory;
          }        

          let root = url+carpeta+"/"+file;

          const transfer = this.transfer.create();

          transfer.download(root, 
           path+"/imgs/"+carpeta+"/"+file).then((entry) => {
              return resolve(true);
           }, (error) => {
              console.log("error", error);        
              return resolve(false);
           });
       });
    }
```

Esto parece que funciona, pero cuando empiezo a descargar todas las imágenes, llega un momento en el que da un error indicando lo siguiente: "The page is temporarily unavailable" (Hay varias que se me descargaron, pero a partir del primer error de este tipo ya no me descarga las siguientes). El error es un 503. Es como si se desconectase el servidor, pero si yo descargo todas las imágenes desde FileZilla, por ejemplo, no hay ningún problema. ¿Algún alma caritativa que pudiera ayudarme? Lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: No es que te *desconectes*, el protocolo HTTP no es orientado a la conexión... tiene pinta de que haces muchas llamadas a la vez y alcanzas el número de conexiones máximas aceptadas por el servidor. ¿Cuántas imágenes descargas?

Comment: Son más de 1000, reconozco que son muchas... Pero las necesito. ¿Se puede modificar algo en el servidor para que lo permita o es imposible?

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, como indicó Pablo (muchas gracias por la ayuda), era una petición masiva y, como sabemos, IONIC trabaja con un lenguaje de programación asíncrono, por lo que lanza todas las peticiones de forma simultánea. Por lo tanto, no se trataba de resolver el problema desde el servidor, sino de controlar esas peticiones.

La solución que encontré yo fue antes de hacer la petición de descarga de las imágenes, crear un archivo zip con todas éstas, descargarlo y, a continuación, descomprimirlo. Y esto resolvió el problema (aclaro que comprimir las imágenes lo hice desde la API y, descargarlo y descomprimirlo desde IONIC).